# Actionscript 3.0 - concurrency

Tags: actionscript-3

development environment : Flash builder 4, SDK 4.1

source code :

```
if (ColonyHandler.getInstance() != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    var colonyA:ColonyHandler = ColonyHandler.getInstance();
                    trace(colonyA);
                    ColonyHandler.getInstance().onMouseMove(event); 
                }
                catch(error:*)
                {
                    var colonyB:ColonyHandler = ColonyHandler.getInstance();
                    trace(colonyB);
                }
            }
```

question : colonyA is not null, colonyB is null. getInstance() method return static variable named '
instance'. is this possible?

Comment: ColonyHandler.getInstance() ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getInstance` is used on singleton classes to get the only instance of a class. This instance is to be stored as a static variable of the class itself (in your case `ColonyHandler`) and is likely to be called "instance". So I don't see anything wrong with what you get: you ask for the only instance of 'ColonyHandler' and get it...